# How do I add a dependency to my Yeoman project when there is no generator

Tags: yeoman

What steps do I need to do in order to add a new dependency library to my Yeoman project. For example, what if I wanted to add Sammy.js or AngularUI. I don't see a generator for either of those so I would have to manually add them. But what other files do I need to edit so the project builds and runs correctly?

Below are some of the generators I searched for

```
npm search yeoman-generator | grep sammy
npm search yeoman-generator | grep angular-ui
npm search yeoman-generator | grep angularui
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to install things like Angular UI using [Bower](http://bower.io/) which is part of the [Yeoman workflow](http://yeoman.io/gettingstarted.html) along with [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

Both of those packages do exist in the Bower registry:

```
$ bower search sammy
Search results:

    sammy git://github.com/quirkey/sammy.git
$ bower search angular-ui
Search results:

    angular-ui git://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui.git
    angular-ui-bootstrap-bower git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower
    angular-ui-bootstrap git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap.git
    angular-ui-router git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
    angular-ui-utils git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils.git
    angular-ui-select2 git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2.git
    angular-ui-date git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date.git
    angular-ui-calendar git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar.git
    angular-ui-codemirror git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-codemirror.git
    angular-ui-ace git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace.git
    angular-ui-multi-sortable git://github.com/mostr/angular-ui-multi-sortable.git
    angular-ui-map git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-map.git
```

There's actually a quick example on the 'Getting Started' page linked above, on using Yeoman, Bower and Grunt to scaffold out an Angular project using AngularUI. Including it here for convenience:

```
yo angular
bower install angular-ui
# then add <script src="components/angular-ui/build/angular-ui.js"></script>
# and <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/angular-ui/build/angular-ui.css"/>
grunt
```

Comment: Just typing 'bower search' is especially useful when you don't know the exact name of the library you are looking for. It outputs everything in bower's universe.

Comment: What about if the package is not available in bower or npm , I have install the ngwigets manually dropping the folder with the framework and add the dependency , it works but when I do the dist the script references disappear from the index.html page and only minify the ones that came with the geoman scaffolding

Comment: @Xvegas Bower is very flexible with regard to the endpoint. You can do the registered package name of course, but also: GitHub shorthand, URL, local path, and many other options. Source: [Bower docs for `install`](http://bower.io/docs/api/#install)